# CATransform3D Split UIView in half with 3D Open Door Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation, catransform3d

I was wondering if there is a way to split a UIView (including subviews) in half from the center and make it animate like a door opening, or a letter being unfolded.

While I understand that this can be attained by having 2 UIViews half the size of the UIView, and creating 2 CATransform3D Rotation Animation, the problem is I have 3 (animating) subviews that needs to be split with the UIView.

*One of the subviews is a UIImageView that is animating a GIF, but any subview can animate a GIF.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to create such an animation, but there's no off-the-shelf way to do it. You'd need to write custom Core Animation code.

What I would do would be to take a snapshot of the view, split that snapshot into 2 layers, and then create a set of `CABasicAnimation`s that animate the open door animation.

Explaining how to do that is way, waaaay beyond the scope of an SO post however.

Comment: But, one (or all) of my UIView subviews is a running GIF. Would it be possible to keep it running AND do the 3D animation?

I am sure that snapshot will stop the animation and that is the last thing that I want to happen.

Comment: Right, taking a snapshot would freeze the animation. I'd have to think about another approach in order to do a "barn door" animation with the GIF running at the same time. You might have to create 2 copies of each GIF, each one cropping half the image, and animate them separately.

Comment: but UIView animations allow "animated content"?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think so. Try animating a simple slow rotation of a view that's showing an animated GIF as a test.

Comment: It is animating while I'm making CATransform3DRotate animation. That's what I wanted to recreate. Making a copy of the 3 layers on top of the UIView that I want to animate will double the memory usage for the animation. One running GIF is using 35MB. I have 3 subviews that can animate, if all subviews are animating and I split them to 2, that's 205MB already not counting the App's memory usage.

Comment: How would you split the snapshot into two separate views?